# is https://api.mycompany.com/[URI]?api_token=xxxxxxxx secure enough?

Tags: api, http

we're designing a simple RESTful API. From a pure security standpoint-- if we only allow HTTPS connections, is the "?token=xxxxxxxxxxx" portion encrypted when it's sent over the wire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No GET parameters (the part after '?') are not encrypted. The headers are a better place for the token. You can use the authorization header like this.

```
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx
```

The headers are encrypted where the url (including params) can show up in logs and user history potentially exposing the token.

That said a token in the url can be ok for certain circumstances, especially if it is a short lived token (<1hr)

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. This is where I put it now.